# How to access key pair values of individual elements in an array multiple times in 1 API call?

Tags: javascript, html

The API request that I am using will return an array of elements and within each element, there are multiple key pair values.

A similar response would like this API: https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems, which returns an array of poems.

```
[
 {
  "title": "...."
  "content": "..."
  "url" : "..."
 }
 {
  "title": "...."
  "content": "..."
  "url" : "..."
 }
 {
  "title": "...."
  "content": "..."
  "url" : "..."
 }
]
```

I am using Webflow's embedded code feature to display the responses from the API in multiple boxes:

[image: Example of how data is displayed]

**An example snippet:**

```
<h1 id ="title"></h1>
<p id ="content"></p>
<script>
    fetch("https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const { title, content} = data[0];
        document.getElementById("title").textContent = title
        document.getElementById("content").textContent = content
      });
</script>
```

**My limits:**

In the boxes, there are other unique div classes that contain unique info. So I don't think I can use a for loop.

**My question:**

I could use the exact same snippet 4 times and change the element respectively, but I will be making 4 API calls. Is there a way that I could call the API just once and then access the data individually? Webflow allows you to add a script at the head tag, so the API request do not necessarily need to be inside the individual embedded code snippet.

Comment: What is the problem with for loop i can't get...

Comment: @DmitryReutov I relooked and found a solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 id ="title_0"></h1>
<p id ="content_0"></p>
<script>
    fetch("https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        for (i=0; i<=4; i++){
        const {title, content} = data[i];
        document.getElementById("title_" + i).textContent = title
        document.getElementById("content_" + i).textContent = content
        }
      });
</script>
```